# Adding nodes into graph using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, algorithm, graph, astar

I'm new to qgis and in here I want to find a path between two selected points on the map(Roads-vector layer). The points are selected by the user, using mouse clicks.

So here I used the astar algorithm to find path between two points.

*********************************astar.py************************************
import heapq

class AStar(object):
      def **init**(self, graphAstar):
                self.graphAstar = graphAstar

```
def heuristic(self, node, start, end):
    raise NotImplementedError

def search(self, start, end):
openset = set()
    closedset = set()
    current = start
    openHeap = []
    openset.add(current)
    openHeap.append((0,current))
    while openset:
    temp = heapq.heappop(openHeap)
    current = temp[1]
        if current == end:
            path = []
            while current.parent:
                path.append(current)
                current = current.parent
            path.append(current)
            return path[::-1]
        openset.remove(current)
        closedset.add(current)
        for node in self.graphAstar[current]:
            if node in closedset:
                continue
            if node in openset:
                new_g = current.gg + current.move_cost(node)
                if node.gg > new_g:
                    node.gg = new_g
                    node.parent = current
            else:
                node.gg = current.gg + current.move_cost(node)
                node.H = self.heuristic(node, start, end)
                node.parent = current
                openset.add(node)
        heapq.heappush(openHeap, (node.H,node))
    return None


class AStarNode(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gg = 0
        self.H = 0
        self.parent = None

    def move_cost(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

*****************************astar_grid.py*******************************

```
from astar import AStar, AStarNode
from math import sqrt

class AStarGrid(AStar):
    def heuristic(self, node, start, end):
        return sqrt((end.x - node.x)**2 + (end.y - node.y)**2)

class AStarGridNode(AStarNode):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        super(AStarGridNode, self).__init__()

    def move_cost(self, other):
        diagonal = abs(self.x - other.x) == 1 and abs(self.y - other.y) == 1
        return 14 if diagonal else 10
```

and in the main code, the following method is used to create graph from vector layer.

****************************plugin.py************************************

```
def make_graph(self, mapinfo):
    nodes = [[AStarGridNode(x, y) for y in range(mapinfo['height'])] for x in range(mapinfo['width'])]
    graphAstar = {}
    for x, y in product(range(mapinfo['width']), range(mapinfo['height'])):
        node = nodes[x][y]
        graphAstar[node] = []
        for i, j in product([-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]):
                if not (0 <= x + i < mapinfo['width']): continue
                if not (0 <= y + j < mapinfo['height']): continue
                graphAstar[nodes[x][y]].append(nodes[x+i][y+j])
    return graphAstar, nodes
```

And I called that method in FindRoutes method..

```
def findRoutes(self):
# QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(),"Info", "in findRoutes function" )
# vl = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
vl=self.canvas.currentLayer()
director = QgsLineVectorLayerDirector( vl, -1, '', '', '', 3 )
properter = QgsDistanceArcProperter()
director.addProperter( properter )
# crs = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
crs = self.canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs()
builder = QgsGraphBuilder( crs )

global x1
global y1
global x2
global y2
pStart = QgsPoint( x1, y1 )
pStop = QgsPoint( x2, y2 )
graphAstar, nodes = self.make_graph({ "width": 8, "height": 8 })
paths = AStarGrid(graphAstar)

start, end = ??
path = paths.search(start, end)
```

How do I pass the start and end coordinates to the function above?

Passing them just as coordinates (start, end = pStart, pStop) does not work.

How do add them to the graph created as nodes?